openssl smime cannot decrypt smime file
Here is the smime file: test.p7m
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"; smime-type="enveloped-data"
test: feild Data
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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Here is the openssl script:
openssl smime -decrypt -in ${MimePath} -inform SMIME -inkey ${keyPath}
The only output I get is:
Error reading S/MIME message
6C470000:error:068000D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1_ex:no content 
type:crypto/asn1/asn_mime.c:420:

It says there's no content type, but I can see the file has one at the top. Is there something else I'm missing here, thank you in advance.
